# SQL Server : how to delete particular column's data in all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I have a table like this

```
Id  | Action
----+---------------------------------
 1  | GetUser
 2  | Restriction/GetRestrictedUsers
```

I would like to delete all expressions including **'/'** slash symbol in all records

For instance  `Restriction/GetRestrictedUsers` this should be like this `GetRestrictedUsers`

Any help?

Comment: Why am i getting down-votes?This question has not been found as a duplicate,this question  is not  easy and not  trivial,this question already has  accepted answer with proper solution and this question  is not very long or very short .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Try this (after making a backup of the table):

```
update t
    set action = substring(action, charindex('/', action) + 1, len(action))
    where action like '%/%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update table_name
set Action = SUBSTRING(Action, Charindex('/', action) + 1,len(action))
where action like '%/%';
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) function (2012+) could be abused for this.

```
update [YourTable]
set Action = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Action,'/','.'), 1)
where action like '%/%[^/]';
```